# Similar application to Send to Dropbox

Tags: asp.net, email, iis-7.5, dropbox, email-attachments

I was just wondering, does anybody know if there is a similar application out there that allows you to do the same thing as the "Send to Dropbox" feature on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5? IE. You can define an email address, and when you email that address with an attachment it will save the attachment automatically into a pre-defined folder on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: I would do it using windows service running on the server that checks inbox of specific email address e.g every 60 seconds and if there is new email with attachment it strips attachment, saves file into specified folder and moves email to 'deleted' to not process it again next time. .NET framework has all you need to implement such service.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll have a look into that. Thanks again for your help.